# Не могу понять как работает TransformDirection

Tags: unity3d

```
private void Start()
{
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);
}

void Update()
{
    delta_x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    delta_y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    new_position = new Vector3(delta_x, delta_y);;
    new_position = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(new_position, speed);
    new_position = transform.TransformDirection(new_position);
    transform.Translate(new_position);   
}
```

Вообщем как я понял TransformDirection должен вектор движения преобразовать локальное изменение координат к глобальным. Если старт такой:

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 180);
```

то TransformDirection действительно преобразует вектор изменения к глобальной системе координат, но если старт такой:

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);
```

то все направления становятся противоположными не смотря на TransformDirection. Что в этом коде не так?

Comment: Можно конечно использовать transform.Translate(new_position, Space.World);  , но всё же и первый способ должен работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем вопрос решил способом из первого комментария:

```
transform.Translate(new_position, Space.World);
```

Answer (score 0):

Следующим кодом Вы вектор направления, якобы определённый в локальной системе координат (далее, СК), преобразуете в вектор направления в глобальной СК:

```
new_position = transform.TransformDirection(new_position);
```

Это может иметь смысл для того, что бы узнать, какое перемещение в глобальной СК надо совершить для перемещения на вектор new_position в локальной СК объекта.

Следую кодом Вы перемещаете объект в локальной СК (по умолчанию для метода Translate) в направлении new_position, применимом к глобальной СК:

```
transform.Translate(new_position);
```

И всякий смысл приведений к СК утрачивается.

Что бы объект перемещался вдоль своих локальных осей Х и Y необходимо в Вашем случае использовать один из двух вариантов:

```
// Вариант 1 - явно указываем перемещение в глобальной СК:
transform.Translate(new_position, Space.World);

// Вариант 2 - просто перемещаем объект, раз мы
// получили его глобальное перемещение в переменной new_position:
transform.position += new_position;
```

А ещё лучше - пропустить использование метода TransformDirection, а использовать сразу метод transform.Translate:

```
transform.Translate(new_position);
```

Метод Translate специально предназначен, что бы можно было не переводить глобальные координаты в локальные и перемещать объект в направлениях его локальных координат, так он работает по умолчанию.